# How do I get rid of the white space on the sides of my website? repeat background? resize div? I'm lost

Tags: html, css, background, resize

How do I get rid of the white space on either side of my website?

I want the backgound to be flexible to fit the browser window for whatever size it is. I think I need to resize the div container but I'm having lots of trouble.

http://www.dropshiplounge.com/

Comment: Your bg image and the bar across the top could be made into small images that repeat. Have you tried playing with that?

Comment: Joel, I'm going to give that a try. I'll slice the bg images and repeat them

Answer (score 0):

Your website was built using a fixed width and a margin that aligns it in the middle of the page using this rule in your css.

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Everything within your site has been built to within the specification of your wrapper width. Most responsive sites still have a page wrapper and a maximum width. If it's the white space that bothers set a background to the body element

```
body{background:color;}
```

or for an image

```
body{background-image:url('background_image_url')}
```

While im not the biggest fan of W3C refer to this for more information if you get stuck - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

If you are concerned that your site doesn't respond to different screen sizes and browser resizing then consider hiring a professional to redesign your site for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ktQ/) more or less what you're looking for?

I removed the hard-coded width on `global_container_` and set `width: 100%;` on the header, along with `repeat-x` for the `header` background. I removed `float: left;` from the `header` and it's child elements, and made sure the child elements had left- and right-margins of `auto`. I also removed the hard-coded width from the `headline`, but you'll have to move the `bottomline` outside of it's container if you want that full-width as well (or remove the hard-coded width from the container).

Also, I don't think I had to change this in the fiddle, but you may need to remove the `clearfix` class from `global_container_`, or set it to `display: block;` in order for the full width to take effect.

It's the same idea for the `footer` - set it to `width: 100%;` and adjust the footer and child elements' padding and margin until they're placed where you want them.

Comment: Nicole, it looks good on the fiddle website but when i update the code, the site turns out a bit funky. it's live now http://www.dropshiplounge.com

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by funky? Are you referring to the footer? I didn't add styling to the footer into the fiddle because it's the same idea as what was done for the header. Also, it looks like a lot of the changes I mentioned have not been brought into the live site yet...

Comment: I did a hard refresh and I'm not seeing anything other than a change to the `global_container_` width and background.

Comment: Hmm. that's strange. Ok, I'm going to switch back to the original.